# Find the value of $777^{1234} \pmod {1111}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I'm having trouble solving this modulus question with irregular and large numbers.
After using Euler's Theorem, I managed to simplify the question to

$$777^{234} \pmod {1111}$$
Indeed,

$1111 = 11 * 101$, and therefore

$\phi(1111) = (11 - 1)(101 - 1) = 1000$.

However I have no idea how to continue from here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try answering the two simpler questions of $777^{234}\pmod{11}$ and $777^{234}\pmod{101}$ and combining those to one final answer.

Comment: From $x\equiv3\pmod{11}\\x\equiv88\pmod{101}$ you have, for example,$x=88+101M$ so $88+101M\equiv3\pmod{11}$ so $0+2M\equiv3\pmod{11}\Rightarrow M=7+11N$. Finally $x=88+101(7+11N)=88+707+101\cdot 11N$ ¿What $101\cdot 11$ is?

Answer (score 2):

$777\equiv 7\pmod {11}; 7^{10}\equiv1\pmod{11}$; so $777^{234}\equiv7^4\pmod{11}$  and finally $777^{234}\equiv3\pmod {11}$

$777\equiv70\pmod {101}$; $70^5\equiv 6\pmod{101}$; $(70^5)^{40}\equiv1\pmod{101}$...

Hope this helps you get to the end.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.- One has $1111=11\cdot101 \\777\equiv7\pmod{11}\equiv{70}\pmod{101}\\\\1234=2\cdot617\\ 617=56\cdot11+1=6\cdot101+11$ Consequently we have
$$777^{1234}\equiv7^{2(56\cdot11+1)}\equiv49^{56\cdot11}\cdot49\equiv49^2\pmod{11}\equiv5^2\pmod{11}\\777^{1234}\equiv7^{2(6\cdot101+11)}\equiv49\cdot49^{11}\equiv49^{12}\equiv88\pmod{101}$$ So you have
$$x\equiv3\pmod{11}\\x\equiv88\pmod{101}$$
Apply now chinese theorem.